# ObjectOutputstream/ObjectInputStream not sending everytime

Tags: java, networking, serialization, stream

Im new to network programming and I am doing a chatprogram in java. I first used DataOutputStream and It worked fine, but I thought it would be more neat if I used Object Streams, enabling me to send user information. The thing is that ObjectOutPutStream does not send everytime for me. In fact it has the regular pattern of sending every third time. Same deal with the server's messages, the client receives them every third time.

Here is some code:

Client side:

```
public void start() throws IOException{ 
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    if (thread == null) {
        client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

}

public void sendMessage(String msg){
    try {
        output.writeObject(new Message(msg));
        output.flush();
    }catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Sending error: " + ioe.getMessage());
        stop();
    }
}
```

Server side:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Server Thread " + ID + " running.");
    while (true) {
        try {
            if(streamIn.readObject() instanceof Message){
                System.out.println((Message)streamIn.readObject());
                server.handleMessage(ID, (Message)streamIn.readObject());
            }   
        }catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Listening error: " + ex.getMessage());
                server.remove(ID);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Class was not found");
        }

    }


}
public void open() throws IOException {
    streamOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    streamIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The question will probably require a decent [mcve] to be solvable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is that you read multiple times from `ObjectInputStream` assuming that all this times you will get same object. But infact you are just losing it and read next one.

Try to rewrite your server code like this:

```
    System.out.println("Server Thread " + ID + " running.");
    while (true) {
        try {
            Object message = streamIn.readObject();
            if (message instanceof Message) {
                System.out.println((Message) message);
                server.handleMessage(ID, (Message) message);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Listening error: " + ex.getMessage());
            server.remove(ID);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Class was not found");
        }

    }
```

Note how the message was only read once per loop and stored in the variable `message` where it could be tested.

Also I would add `else` block with logging message which for some reason happens to be not instance of `Message`. And print actual exceptions with stacktrace in `catch` blocks.